# Symfony2: include raw file in Twig Template

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to include a raw file (`user-actions.log`) to a Template.

The file is saved in `/MyBundle/Ressources/views/Admin/user-actions.log` (could change directory if necessary)

Trying to include file with `{{ include('MyBundle:Admin:user-actions.log) }}` or `{% include 'MyBundle:Admin:user-actions.log' }}` doesnt work because it isn't a `.twig`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Write up an twig extension

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class Extension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    private $kernel;
    private $service_container;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel, $service_container)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        $this->service_container = $service_container;
    }

        public function getFunctions()
        {
            return array(
                'includeFile'            =>  new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'includeFile')
            );
       }

        public function includeFile($file)
        {
            return file_get_contents($file);
        }

}
```

In services.yml

```
parameters:
     acme.twig.extension.class: Acme\AcmeBundle\Twig\Extension

services:
   acme.twig.extension:
      class: %acme.twig.extension.class%
      arguments:
          kernel: "@kernel"
          service_container: "@service_container"
      tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

In your twig templates you can use

```
{{ includeFile(your_path_to_the_file.log) }}
```

More docs 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Thank you. Is there no other solution without writing an extension? I would prefer to keep my project as simple as possible.

Comment: Twig dose not support including non template files. Another way around this is to get the file contents in your controller and pass it to the template.

Comment: You're right, guess it was too late for me for the simple Controller based solution xD